# Generic variant of bi f a b = (f a, f b)

Tags: haskell, types, higher-rank-types

Is there any type-safe way to write a function

```
bi f a b = (f a, f b)
```

such that it would be possible to use it like this:

```
x1 :: (Integer, Char)
x1 = bi head [2,3] "45"

x2 :: (Integer, Char)
x2 = bi fst (2,'3') ('4',5)

x3 :: (Integer, Double)
x3 = bi (1+) 2 3.45
```

?
In rank-n-types examples there are always something much simpler like

```
g :: (forall a. a -> a) -> a -> a -> (a, a)
g f a b = (f a, f b)
```

Comment: I don't think so.  You'd have to quantify it over all input types, which requires abstracting over typeclass constraints.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, there are some new stuff (ConstraintKinds) which allows to abstract over constraints.

Comment: Okay, I see that, but I don't think you can quantify over the result types like you'd have to.  If it had the form `a -> a`, you could do  `bi :: (cxt a, cxt b) => (forall x . cxt x => x -> x) -> a -> b -> (a, b)`, but I don't think you can automatically get the "type function" from each input to its result type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, though not in Haskell. But the higher-order polymorphic lambda calculus (aka System F-omega) is more general:

```
bi : forall m n a b. (forall a. m a -> n a) -> m a -> m b -> (n a, n b)
bi {m} {n} {a} {b} f x y = (f {a} x, f {b} y)

x1 : (Integer, Char)
x1 = bi {\a. List a} {\a. a} {Integer} {Char} head [2,3] "45"

x2 : (Integer, Char)
x2 = bi {\a . exists b. (a, b)} {\a. a} {Integer} {Char} (\{a}. \p. unpack<b,x>=p in fst {a} {b} x) (pack<Char, (2,'3')>) (pack<Integer, ('4',5)>)

x3 : (Integer, Double)
x3 = bi {\a. a} {\a. a} {Integer} {Double} (1+) 2 3.45
```

Here, I write `f {T}` for explicit type application and assume a library typed respectively. Something like `\a. a` is a type-level lambda. The `x2` example is more intricate, because it also needs existential types to locally "forget" the other bit of polymorphism in the arguments.

You can actually simulate this in Haskell by defining a `newtype` or datatype for every different `m` or `n` you instantiate with, and pass appropriately wrapped functions `f` that add and remove constructors accordingly. But obviously, that's no fun at all.

**Edit**: I should point out that this still isn't a *fully* general solution. For example, I can't see how you could type

```
swap (x,y) = (y,x)
x4 = bi swap (3, "hi") (True, 3.1)
```

even in System F-omega. The problem is that the `swap` function is more polymorphic than `bi` allows, and unlike with `x2`, the other polymorphic dimension is not forgotten in the result, so the existential trick does not work. It seems that you would need kind polymorphism to allow that one (so that the argument to `bi` can be polymorphic over a varying number of types).

Answer (score 6):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

bi f = [| \a b -> ($f a, $f b)|]
```

```
ghci> :set -XTemplateHaskell 
ghci> $(bi [|head|]) [2,3] "45" 
(2,'4')
```

;)

Answer (score 3):

Even with ConstraintKinds, I think the barrier is going to be quantifying over the "type function" from the arguments to the results.  What you *want* is for `f` to map `a -> b` and `c -> d`, and to take `a -> b -> (c, d)`, but I don't think there's any way to quantify over that relationship with full generality.

Some special cases might be doable, though:

```
(forall x . cxt x => x -> f x) -> a -> b -> (f a, f b)
 -- e.g. return

(forall x . cxt x => f x -> x) -> f a -> f b -> (a, b)
 -- e.g. snd
(forall x . cxt x => x -> x) -> a -> b -> (a, b)
 -- e.g. (+1)
```

but given that you're trying to quantify over more or less arbitrary type functions, I'm not sure you can make that work.

Answer (score 2):

This is about as close as you're going to get, I think:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
module Data.Function.Bi (bi, Fn(..))

bi :: (Fn i a a', Fn i b b') => i -> a -> b -> (a', b')
bi i a b = (fn i a, fn i b)

class Fn i x x' | i x -> x' where
      fn :: i -> x -> x'
```

Use it like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, RankNTypes,
             FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Function.Bi

data Snd = Snd

instance Fn Snd (a, b) b where
         fn Snd = snd

myExpr1 :: (Int, String)
myExpr1 = bi Snd (1, 2) ("a", "b")
-- myExpr == (2, "b")

data Plus = Plus (forall a. (Num a) => a)

instance (Num a) => Fn Plus a a where
         fn (Plus n) = (+n)

myExpr2 :: (Int, Double)
myExpr2 = bi (Plus 1) (1, 2) (1.3, 5.7)
-- myExpr2 == (3, 6.7)
```

It's very clunky, but as general as possible.

Comment: There are several mistakes in this code. First, an instance of `Fn` takes three arguments, which is not the case in `Fn (Plus a)`. Second, the kind of `Plus` is `*` so `Plus a` is invalid. Last, you need `FlexibleInstances` since the type variable `b` appears twice in the `Snd` instance.